# Rename document in nuxeo

Tags: java, nuxeo

I've a document (folderish) in nuxeo I want to rename. I get the `DocumentModel` by uid using the API, and I'm trying to chenge the actual nuxeo name so that his path changes (not just like renaming a blob attachment name, the whole folderish should change name)

I tried changing the properties:

```
DocumentModel cf = this.getCampaignFolder();
cf.setProperty("dublincore", "title", newShortName);
```

This does seems to change the title, but leaves the nuxeo name unchanged.

I tried changing the path:

```
cf.setPathInfo(cf.getPathAsString().replaceAll("/[^/]*$", "), newShortName);
```

but when I save that it says the document doesn't exist.

Can't find a rename or move API either.

How do you rename stuff?

Currently, as a workaround, I am deleting the folder and recreating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your Nuxeo version?

There are:

- [`org.nuxeo.ecm.core.api.CoreSession.move(DocumentRef, DocumentRef, String)`](http://community.nuxeo.com/api/nuxeo/7.4/javadoc/org/nuxeo/ecm/core/api/CoreSession.html#move-org.nuxeo.ecm.core.api.DocumentRef-org.nuxeo.ecm.core.api.DocumentRef-java.lang.String-)
- [`org.nuxeo.ecm.core.model.Session.move(Document, Document, String)`](http://community.nuxeo.com/api/nuxeo/7.4/javadoc/org/nuxeo/ecm/core/model/Session.html#move-org.nuxeo.ecm.core.model.Document-org.nuxeo.ecm.core.model.Document-java.lang.String-)

You could do something like:

```
session.move(doc.getRef(), null, newShortName);
```

Comment: I'm on the 7.3 - don't know how I missed the move on the CoreSession, duh, thanks!

Comment: `org.nuxeo.ecm.core.model.Session` is low level and not accessible to the developer in general. Use CoreSession.